# How to save gridview templated Item data into DB as well as generate a word document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ms-word

I have few textbox which is outside of gridview and a templated item gridview, on button click which is outside of gridview. I want to save data into database table as well as generate a word document.

In word doc. data will show something like this

PO No: 123
Company Name: xyz
Order No: 12345

Item   Qty   Description
 1  2   test1
 2  4   test2

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPONumber" runat="server" Text="PO Number"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPONumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text="Company Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblOrderNo" runat="server" Text="Order Number"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvOrder_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Line Item">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" CssClass="Gridtextboxes" Width="150px" Text='<% #   Eval("Item")%>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Return Quantity">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="gridt" Width="150px" Text='<% # Eval("Quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Description">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductDescription" runat="server" CssClass="Gridtextboxes" Width="150px" Text='<% # Eval("ProductDescription")%>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <center>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Remove" ImageUrl="Images/close.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" /></center>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="110px" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" />
```

Inserting data in DB is okay I have done with that and I have Created a word doc. template something like this.

PO Number: #PONumber#

Invoice Number: #InvoiceNumber#

Line Item : #LineItem#

Return Quantity : #ReturnQuantity#

Product Description : #ProductDescription#

Is there any way in which I can replay word doc #Data# with my aspx page data?

Comment: you can create two function one to save data into database and second is to generate a word file in the format which you want and call both function on your click event.

Comment: @amitesh: can you please give some sample code for generating the doc file

Comment: @Rockey http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12486/export-gridview-data-to-excel-word-pdf-text-and-csv-forma.aspx this link will help you and if you want selected column for your grid-view on doc format you can also do that

Comment: you want to save data into database for the textboxes which are outside of gridview and show that data inside gridview and then export that gridview into doc format?????

Comment: I found some solution from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384 but as I have created a .rtf file and created a template, how to replace the content Placeholder #Data# by textbox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384)

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

 protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
            Word._Application oWord;
            Word._Document oDoc;
            oWord = new Word.Application();
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            object oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;

            Word.Paragraph oParag;
            oParag = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
            oParag.Range.Text = "Return Order";
            oParag.Range.Font.Bold = 2;
            oParag.Format.SpaceAfter = 30;
            oParag.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara1;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara1.Range.Text = "Date: " + txtDate.Text;
            oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara2;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara2.Range.Text = "PO Number: " + txtPONumber.Text;
            oPara2.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara3;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara3.Range.Text = "Invoice Number: " + txtnvoiceNo.Text;
            oPara3.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara4;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara4 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara4.Range.Text = "Company Name or Dealer Name: " + txtCompanyName.Text;
            oPara4.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara4.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara4.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara5;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara5 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara5.Range.Text = "Order Number: " + txtOrderNo.Text;
            oPara5.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara5.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara5.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara6;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara6 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara6.Range.Text = "Contact Person to Return: " + txtReturnPerson.Text;
            oPara6.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara6.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara6.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            Word.Paragraph oPara7;
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oPara7 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
            oPara7.Range.Text = "Email: " + txtEmail.Text;
            oPara7.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            oPara7.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
            oPara7.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            //inserting table
            Word.Table oTable;
            int iTblRowCount = gvReturnOrders.Rows.Count + 1;
            Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, iTblRowCount, 3, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;

            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "Line Item";
            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Text = "Return Quantity";
            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Text = "Product Description";
            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Bold = 1;
            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Bold = 1;
            oTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Bold = 1;

            int iRowCount, iCount = 2;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            for (iRowCount = 1; iRowCount <= gvReturnOrders.Rows.Count; iRowCount++)
            {
                TextBox txtboxLineItems = (TextBox)gvReturnOrders.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtLineItem");
                TextBox txtBoxQty = (TextBox)gvReturnOrders.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtReturnQuantity");
                TextBox txtBoxproductDescription = (TextBox)gvReturnOrders.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtProductDescription");
                oTable.Rows[iCount].Cells[1].Range.Text = txtboxLineItems.Text;
                oTable.Rows[iCount].Cells[2].Range.Text = txtBoxQty.Text;
                oTable.Rows[iCount].Cells[3].Range.Text = txtBoxproductDescription.Text;
                iCount++;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            //var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}.doc", Guid.NewGuid()); // for Unique Id
            string fileName = "C:\\ReturnOrder.doc";
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Delete(fileName);
                oDoc.SaveAs2("C:\\ReturnOrder.doc");
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "Successful";
            }
            else
            {
                oDoc.SaveAs2("C:\\ReturnOrder.doc");
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "Successful";
            }
            oDoc.Close();
            oWord.Quit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I swear by Aspose. They have fantastic tools for working with Office documents and PDF files. They are pretty expensive though but each time I've used the tools I've saved weeks of work so it ends up being cheaper in the end.

Comment: I don't want to use any 3rd party tools for that

Comment: We use OpenXML at work, you can download it as a NuGet package. You can work with the newer docx versions of Word with it. It's free, its by Microsoft and its much harder to use than Aspose IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use any third party.

First you need to all the data from the grid and text box to the database.

```
protected void btnAddCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < gvTrip.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                        string strTripDate = DateValidator.ConvertToMMDDYYYY(txtCopyTripDt.Text).ToString();
                        string strRouteSlcn = Convert.ToString(((Label)gvTrip.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgRouteSlcn2")).Text.Trim());
                        string strTripStartTime = Convert.ToString(((Label)gvTrip.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgTripStartTime")).Text.Trim());
                        string strTripEndTime = Convert.ToString(((Label)gvTrip.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgTripEndTime")).Text.Trim());
                        objMasterTransport.**insertTripDetail**(strTripDate, strRouteSlcn, strTripStartTime, strTripEndTime);
objMasterTransport.**YourFunctionForGenWordFile**(strTripDate, strRouteSlcn, strTripStartTime, strTripEndTime);
                    txtCopyTripDt.Text = null;
                    gvTrip.DataBind();
                    BindData();
       }
    }
```

insertTripDetail is my function some where.I have deleted some code.

Example for generating word file is(from the net)

```
protected void ExportToWord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Get the data from database into datatable
    string strQuery = "select CustomerID, ContactName, City, PostalCode" +
                      " from customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=DataTable.doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

you can either get the data from the database or store it in those variables (strTripDate, strRouteSlcn, strTripStartTime, strTripEndTime)

this is the code link for excel update
http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/populating-word-2007-templates-through-open-xml/