# C# ASP.NET Cannot insert a Gridview into a Word Template document

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ms-word

I am battling to successfully insert an existing WebForm GridView into a Word Template document bookmark. I have all the text inserts working well but the GridView insert I have no idea what I am doing. Here is the code:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
                            Word._Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
                            oWord.Visible = true;
                            Word.Table oTable;
                            int r, c;
                            string strText;
                            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                            object saveWithDocument = true;
                            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */
                            object oTemplate = @"C:\Users\Client\Desktop\iConnect - Proposal v20-2019.11.28.docx";
                            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["CompanyName"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(Session["QCustomer"].ToString()); //this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["Contact"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(Session["QContact"].ToString());//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["CellTel"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(Session["ANumber"].ToString());//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["DateTime"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["QuoteName"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(DateTime.Now.ToString(txtQuoteName.Text));//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["QuoteNo"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(DateTime.Now.ToString(lblQuoteNo.Text));//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["Page2Customer"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(Session["QContact"].ToString());//this is working
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["Signature"].Select();
                            oWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\Client\iConnect SA (PTY) Ltd\Systems Development - Documents\Source Code\iSales\IS1\IS1\Signature\ICSignature.jpg", ref oMissing, ref saveWithDocument, ref oMissing);//this is working
                            //Add Grid View - Once Off
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["OnceOffGridview"].Select();
                            GetGridviewData(dgvEdit);//fetches the gridview data and converts to string builder - this is working
                            oWord.Selection.Paste(GetGridviewData(dgvEdit));//Here I need to insert the gridview into my Word document
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["OnceOffExVat"].Select();//this is working
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(lblSubTotal.Text);//this is working
                            //Add 
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["MonthlyGridview"].Select();
                            //oWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(GetGridviewData(dgvEdit), ref oMissing, ref saveWithDocument, ref oMissing);
                            oDoc.Bookmarks["MOnthlyExVat"].Select();//this is working
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(lblSubTotal.Text);//this is working'''
```

Comment: The COM application Word knows nothing about the .NET GridView. It can't be inserted directly. What kind of result would you want/expect? A table? Something else? Have you searched this before asking? When I search the terms `[ms-word] gridview` on Stack Overflow I get quite a few "hits"...

Comment: For example: [How to save gridview templated Item data into DB as well as generate a word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779350/how-to-save-gridview-templated-item-data-into-db-as-well-as-generate-a-word-docu)